# Can not create a session on Node server

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session, passport-local

I am trying to create a node server with login, logout, authentication features. My code has some sort of problem and after debugging it, some debug info log is generated that I couldn't understand or find on google.

Problems:

1. Routes that need authentication before accessing is allowing to access without a login or a cookie.
2. Also, cookie gets set after login, but the cookie still remains after signing off.

Debug Information :

1. When no cookie set and trying to visit localhost:3000/

express-session log :

> express-session no SID sent, generating session +0ms

2. When post localhost:3000/login/password with valid credentials

express-session log :

> express-session no SID sent, generating session +0ms

> express-session no SID sent, generating session +3m

> express-session set-cookie connect.sid=s%3AuQgx27XnqODttfCECNGsaeJLOWZhk04e.qnHVj9HmUs2svxtb4mb6R9xpw3imbf0kUEhOiRlNXr4; Path=/; HttpOnly +105ms

> express-session split response +9ms

> express-session fetching uQgx27XnqODttfCECNGsaeJLOWZhk04e +439ms

> express-session session found +8ms

> express-session touching +5ms

> express-session split response +2ms

> express-session touched +10ms

3. When post localhost:3000/logout

express-session log :

> express-session fetching uQgx27XnqODttfCECNGsaeJLOWZhk04e +2m

> express-session session found +4ms

> express-session saving uQgx27XnqODttfCECNGsaeJLOWZhk04e +18ms

> express-session set-cookie connect.sid=s%3ADEXRlWTn14GqFZU06YdLC-bemM8rn_ri.1v71XtDmg88F5brCD5yy3BsLvQ1UuGv%2FYS3vTeWD%2FUk; Path=/; HttpOnly +40ms

> express-session split response +6ms

> express-session fetching DEXRlWTn14GqFZU06YdLC-bemM8rn_ri +144ms

> express-session session found +1ms

> express-session touching +1ms

> express-session split response +1ms

> express-session touched +2ms

I'm just trying to understand these concepts and I understand I'm not following a good coding practice. This is the code file.

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const doten = require("dotenv");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const courses = [
  { name: "aa", class: 5 },
  { name: "bb", class: 7 },
  { name: "cc", class: 8 },
  { name: "dd", class: 4 },
];
const user = [{}];
var passport = require("passport");
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local");
var session = require("express-session");

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(function verify(username, password, cb) {
    if (username == 1 && password == 1) return cb(null, username);
    else return cb(null, false, { message: "Incorrect username or password." });
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: false },
  })
);

app.use(passport.authenticate("session"));
passport.serializeUser(function (username, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    return cb(null, {
      username: username,
    });
  });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, cb) {
  process.nextTick(function () {
    return cb(null, user);
  });
});

app.post(
  "/login/password",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
  })
);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    name: "Sourabh Roy",
    class: 9,
    section: "A",
    roll: 27,
    pass: "PASSED",
  });
});
app.get("/books/:name", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ ...req.params, ...req.query });
});

app.post("/signup", (req, res) => {
  let temp_user = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);
  user.push(temp_user);
  res.send(req.body);
});

app.post("/logout", function (req, res, next) {
  req.logout(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});

//process.env.SERVER_PORT
app.listen(3000, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log("hi");
  else console.log("Server is up at port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use session store service as currently session stores on server side memory which causing issues.

In my opinion you need to use redis for session storage. here is a module that you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis

It mention detail to connect redis with session module as well.